# How to apply code style in IntelliJ/AndroidStudio to whole project?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have recently changed my code style and I want to apply it to the whole project and commit it to repo in one shoot.

I'm able to reformat a class by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+L but it only applies to a single open class. I'm looking for a way to apply my change all classes of project. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try selecting the radio button "Whole Project" instead of the individual file under `Code>Reformat`

Additionally, you could right click the folder in the tree and choose Reformat from there.